# Switch between opened files in MonoDevelop Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

How can I switch between opened files in MonoDevelop opened from Unity. ALT-TAB doesn't work. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Don't misuse it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> should do the trick

for Mac: <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>LeftArrow</kbd> and <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>RightArrow</kbd>

don't know if it has been fixed yet, but there has been problems with this keybind before (in 2.4 on windows)

Comment: I am using Mac Os and CTRL + TAB doesn't work. Also, I have Unity 2.4.

Comment: It works. Thank you. Still, I'm not that happy with pushing 3 keys just to switch between tabs.

Answer (score 1):

As of MonoDevelop 4.0, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> works in both Windows and Mac environments.